# PHP - can't print something really basic

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on my website and I'm having some trouble with PHP syntax. I just want to say "Welcome, [name]" when users are logged in. I'm working on Wordpress and I'm using a plugin to work with users. So, as I want to align the text on the right side of the website, I have this:

```
print"<p align=\"RIGHT\">Welcome, </p>";
```

But now I need to insert the name. For doing that I have a shortcode:

```
[user-data field_name="Name"]
```

I'm trying to put those things together, but is not working. I'm using do_shortcode, but I don't know how to put that together.

```
do_shortcode('[user-data field_name="Nombre"]')
```

Hope someone can help me. thank you very much!

Comment: what plugin are you using?

Comment: You should use CSS instead of `align="RIGHT"`

Comment: `echo do_shortcode('[user-data field_name="Nombre"]');`

Comment: Front-End Users Plugin

Comment: if I use [user-data field_name="Name"] it works fine by itself. The only problem is that I don't know how to put them together so "welcome" and the name are in the same line. (maybe creating a new variable that puts them together before printing them??)

Answer (score 0):

if the plugin is querying the databse table _users you should be able to store the name of the current user in a variable and then add that to your output. I'm not sure what plugin you're using, but try something like this. This is how I've always done it.

```
<?php if(is_user_logged_in()) : ?>
    <?php
        global $current_user;
        get_currentuserinfo();
        $username = $current_user->user_login;
     ?>
    <p class="your-class">Welcome, <?php echo $username; ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

if that doesn't work I would hop into your database and find the table/field where the usernames are being stored and then call/store them in a similar manner